# Python: Why do int.numerator and int.denominator exist?

Tags: python, math, int

`int.numerator` and `int.denominator` are a mystery to me.

`help(int.numerator)` states:

> the numerator of a rational number in lowest terms

But as far as I know, `int` is not a rational number. So why do these properties exist?

Comment: Since when are integers irrational numbers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html - int (`numbers.Integral`) is a subtype of `numbers.Rational`.

```
>>> import numbers
>>> isinstance(1337, numbers.Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(1337, numbers.Rational)
True
>>> issubclass(numbers.Integral, numbers.Rational)
True
```

The denominator of an int is always `1` while its numerator is the value itself.

In [**PEP 3141**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3141/) you find details about the implementation of the various number types, e.g. proving the previous statement:

```
@property
def numerator(self):
    """Integers are their own numerators."""
    return +self

@property
def denominator(self):
    """Integers have a denominator of 1."""
    return 1
```

Comment: I do not think this answer is completely correct. It implies that generally, the numeral classes are identical to the built-in types, which is not the case. A question to discuss along that lines is: Why doesn't float have numerator and denominator?

Comment: @DominikGeorge I think the answer to that question is pretty obvious -- because of floating point imprecision. Try this in your Python shell: `0.23 * 10`. The result is not `2.3` but `2.3000000000000003`, so after multiplying by 10 the numerator and denominator are incorrect, and thus are kind of useless. **Anyways;** this answer is not quite satisfactory, since it doesn't demonstrate the `numerator` and `denominator` properties on a concrete case. So here's one: `fractions.Fraction(4,5).denominator == 5`, and `isinstance(fractions.Fraction(4,5), numbers.Rational) == True`.