# How is it possible that a Python built-in data type can have attributes that have the same data type?

Tags: python, c, recursion, types

Obviously this cannot be done in Python code, such as

```
class Foo:
    a = Foo()
```

but how did they manage to program this when creating the language itself?

Examples include `int` having the attributes `real`, `imag`, `numerator` and `denominator`; `str` having `__doc__`; methods having their own methods and `type` being its own meta class.

How could they get around the recursion caused if you tried to replicate something like this using Python code?

Comment: I don’t know if this answers your question, but internally I think all of these are `PyObject*`s? And the reason you can’t do this in C is that things aren’t pointers by default. The pointer lets you do it without making the object infinitely big.

Comment: Remember that Python strings can just be wrappers for C strings, Python ints wrappers for C ints, etc. One doesn't need to precreate all the possible properties at instantiation time; one just needs the single backing value.

Comment: And you certainly _can_ have `Foo.a` in Python be another `foo`. Same rules apply -- create it at runtime, or after bootstrapping, etc.

Comment: Anyhow, what's the specific problem you encountered that this answer will help you fix? Questions that are based on mere curiosity are often off-topic here; Help Center guidelines call for questions to be *practical* -- that is to say, to have a concrete impact on how you go about the practice of programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your assumption is not exactly true. You can assign to class members after the class has been created. Consider the following:

```
# Class definition
class Foo:

    foo = None

    def the_foo(self):
        return Foo.foo

# Assigning to the class member
Foo.foo = Foo()

# Creating an object and accessing class member through an object method
a_foo = Foo()
print("type(a_foo.the_foo()) =", type(a_foo.the_foo()))
```

This yields:

```
type(a_foo.the_foo()) = <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

So, if this can be done in Python, why not in built-in classes?

Comment: This is true, but it also doesn't particularly answer the question about how CPython works. (The `int` and `string` types are implemented in C, not in native Python at all).

Comment: It actually does answer the question, which was "how is it possible?" rather than "how is it done?". The premise was that since Python does not allow a construct, its C implementation surely does not allow it, either. I demonstrated that the original assumption was incorrect, thus making the point moot. It would have also been possible to show that the assumption does not lead to the conclusion, but I did not bother with that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is along the lines of what you need to achieve.
But a neat workaround might be to use `@property` decorators?

```
class Foo:

    @property
    def a(self):
        return Foo()

x = Foo()
print(x)
print(x.a)
print(type(x) == type(x.a) == Foo)
```

```py
<__main__.Foo object at 0x033083B8>
<__main__.Foo object at 0x033081D8>
True
```

Technically this gets you around the recursion. It strictly speaking won't create the second instance immediately, so if that's a factor you need to take into consideration neither mine or Amitai's answers will do that for you. But it will create a property on instance creation called `a` but won't do anything until you access it.

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to achieve something in their own code; the question is asking how *CPython* achieved a thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yepp, and [this is one way](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/numbers.py#L384-L387) that they do it. Or at least that's what I gathered from the source code. And [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156777/python-why-do-int-numerator-and-int-denominator-exist) some more info on the topic.